# The instance of entity type '' cannot be tracked as the entity type '' because the two types are not in the same hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

After migrating from .net 5 to .net 6 I've start to get randomly this error in the production environment:

> "The instance of entity type 'subentity' cannot be tracked as the entity type
> 'subentity' because the two types are not in the same hierarchy."

In an intent to isolate de code that produce the error I get the following:
(I call to the Test1 api and then to the Test2 api. It crash in the  attributes.Db.SaveChanges() line)
If I change the compiled queries to normal queries it fix the error aparently.

TestController.cs:

```cs
public TestController(TestContext db)
{
    attributes = new ControllerAttributes(db);
}

private static readonly Func<TestContext, int> GetByIdQry =
    EF.CompileQuery((TestContext db, int id) =>
        db.TestEntity.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id));

[HttpGet("Test")]
public void Test()
{
    var db2 = TestContext.GetContext();

    var testEntity= new TestEntity();

    testEntity.SubEntity = SubEntity.Get(attributes.Db, "29028383"); 

    db2.Dispose();
}

[HttpGet("Test2")]
public void Test2()
{
    TestEntity testEntity= GetByIdQry(attributes.Db, 263285);

    testEntity.SubEntity= SubEntity.Get(attributes.Db, "29028383");

    attributes.Db.SaveChanges(); //here crash 
}
```

Subentity.cs:

```cs
private static readonly Func<TestContext, string, SubEntity> GetQuery =
    EF.CompileQuery((TestContext db, string number)
        => db.Subentity.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Number== number );

public static Subentity Get(TestContext db, string number)
{
    return GetQuery(db, number);
}
```

Entity.cs:

```cs
    public class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SubEntityId { get; set; }
        public virtual SubEntity SubEntity { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the entity classes.

Comment: Post the *relevant* classes. The error complains about classes s**ub**entity and s**ib**entity. Your code though uses `SubEntity`. Where did the error occur? What are the *actual* classes and *actual error*?

Comment: Sorry about the typing error. Sibentity means subentity i've already edited it. As i describe in the post the error happend in the attributes.Db.SaveChanges(); of Test2